# UpdateCommand only when at least one field has changed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Is it possible to have the UpdateCommand fire only when one of the fields has actually changed?  One of the fields is a timestamp, and I don't want the timestamp to be updated unless one of the fields values has actually changed?

This is ASP front end, there's nothing relating to it in the CodeBehind.  Not sure if it matters but I'm using an Infragistics WebDataGrid control.

Here's the lines, let me know if you need more of them:

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="tblClaimRoster" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:RosterConnectionString %>"
        ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT RosterID, [EE Name] AS EE_Name, [EEID], [Mgr Name] AS Mgr_Name, [Adjustment trained] AS Adjustment_trained, [Appeal trained] AS Appeal_trained, [ARGUS], [Auto Reversal] AS Auto_Reversal, [CBH D G] AS CBH_D_G, [CBH Proclaim] AS CBH_Proclaim, [CCE Tool Access] AS CCE_Tool_Access, [CCP], [CCR], [Checks Rework] AS Checks_Rework, [Chiro Occ Phys Home] AS Chiro_Occ_Phys_Home, [RA], [RDE], [Puerto Rico] AS Puerto_Rico, [Speech Vision Therapy] AS Speech_Vision_Therapy, [Stop Loss Calc] AS Stop_Loss_Calc, [Surg Anes] AS Surg_Anes, [Transplant], [Non Standard Contracts] AS Non_Standard_Contracts, [One View] AS One_View, [Pharmacy], [PMHS], [Post Pricing] AS Post_Pricing, [Pre D] AS Pre_D, [Proclaim], [Lifesource], [Maternity], [Medicare Hospital] AS Medicare_Hospital, [Medicaid], [Medicare Physician] AS Medicare_Physician, [MSP], [Negative Balance] AS Negative_Balance, [Foreign Claim] AS Foreign_Claim, [Hospital Standard] AS Hospital_Standard, [iCare], [ILWU], [iSave], [iView], [iTrack], [Correspondence trained] AS Correspondence_trained, [Defined Care] AS Defined_Care, [Dental Dentacom] AS Dental_Dentacom, [Dental Webster] AS Dental_Webster, [Dialysis], [ECPP], [Virgin Islands] AS Virgin_Islands, [Facets], [cFunds], [SAR], [Alliance], [MERPS], [Proclaim Green Screens] AS Proclaim_Green_Screens, [tblclaimRoster_Status], [Skill 1] AS Skill_1, [Skill 2] AS Skill_2, [Medicom], [CIGNA Claims] AS CIGNA_Claims, [Effective date in current role] AS Effective_date_in_current_role, [Time Stamp] AS Time_Stamp, [MSDRG], [ALI], [Call Trained] AS Call_Trained, [Dedicated Acct Taft Hartley] AS Dedicated_Acct_Taft_Hartley, [Dedicated Acct SOI] AS Dedicated_Acct_SOI, [SANP], [Dedicated Acct J J] AS Dedicated_Acct_J_J, [Xprtr], [VOB], [Hospital Non Standard] AS Hospital_Non_Standard FROM [tblclaimRoster] ORDER BY [EE Name] ASC"
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE [tblclaimRoster] SET [EE Name] = @EE_Name, [EEID] = @EEID, [Mgr Name] = @Mgr_Name, [Adjustment trained] = @Adjustment_trained, [Appeal trained] = @Appeal_trained, [ARGUS] = @ARGUS, [Auto Reversal] = @Auto_Reversal, [CBH D G] = @CBH_D_G, [CBH Proclaim] = @CBH_Proclaim, [CCE Tool Access] = @CCE_Tool_Access, [CCP] = @CCP, [CCR] = @CCR, [Checks Rework] = @Checks_Rework, [Chiro Occ Phys Home] = @Chiro_Occ_Phys_Home, [RA] = @RA, [RDE] = @RDE, [Puerto Rico] = @Puerto_Rico, [Speech Vision Therapy] = @Speech_Vision_Therapy, [Stop Loss Calc] = @Stop_Loss_Calc, [Surg Anes] = @Surg_Anes, [Transplant] = @Transplant, [Non Standard Contracts] = @Non_Standard_Contracts, [One View] = @One_View, [Pharmacy] = @Pharmacy, [PMHS] = @PMHS, [Post Pricing] = @Post_Pricing, [Pre D] = @Pre_D, [Proclaim] = @Proclaim, [Lifesource] = @Lifesource, [Maternity] = @Maternity, [Medicare Hospital] = @Medicare_Hospital, [Medicaid] = @Medicaid, [Medicare Physician] = @Medicare_Physician, [MSP] = @MSP, [Negative Balance] = @Negative_Balance, [Foreign Claim] = @Foreign_Claim, [Hospital Standard] = @Hospital_Standard, [iCare] = @iCare, [ILWU] = @ILWU, [iSave] = @iSave, [iView] = @iView, [iTrack] = @iTrack, [Correspondence trained] = @Correspondence_trained, [Defined Care] = @Defined_Care, [Dental Dentacom] = @Dental_Dentacom, [Dental Webster] = @Dental_Webster, [Dialysis] = @Dialysis, [ECPP] = @ECPP, [Virgin Islands] = @Virgin_Islands, [Facets] = @Facets, [cFunds] = @cFunds, [SAR] = @SAR, [Alliance] = @Alliance, [MERPS] = @MERPS, [Proclaim Green Screens] = @Proclaim_Green_Screens, [tblclaimRoster_Status] = @tblclaimRoster_Status, [Skill 1] = @Skill_1, [Skill 2] = @Skill_2, [Medicom] = @Medicom, [CIGNA Claims] = @CIGNA_Claims, [Effective date in current role] = @Effective_date_in_current_role, [Time Stamp] = GetDate(), [MSDRG] = @MSDRG, [ALI] = @ALI, [Call Trained] = @Call_Trained, [Dedicated Acct Taft Hartley] = @Dedicated_Acct_Taft_Hartley, [Dedicated Acct SOI] = @Dedicated_Acct_SOI, [SANP] = @SANP, [Dedicated Acct J J] = @Dedicated_Acct_J_J, [Xprtr] = @Xprtr, [VOB] = @VOB, [Hospital Non Standard] = @Hospital_Non_Standard WHERE [RosterID] = @RosterID">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Sorry for the extra-long list of fields, but the TimeStamp one is close to the end.

EDIT: Attached are 2 images showing the order of the array.
[image: New Values]
[image: New Values 2]

---

[image: Old Values]
[image: Old Values 2]

Answer (score 1):

Use the GridView `OnRowUpdating` event  which is called just before when update is about to be done. You can examine your values and cancel the update operation.

in this `OnRowUpdating`  event Handler, you pass `GridViewUpdateEventArgs`  as an argument. This provides two properties: `NewValues` to get the new/updated values and `OldValues` to get your old values which you will check against your new values.  [ Note the use of `e.NewValues` & `e.OldValues` ]

You cancel the update operation by setting `e.Cancel=true`

[Refer MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewupdateeventargs.aspx) too.

```
<asp:GridView ID="CustomersGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" 
  AllowSorting="true"   OnRowUpdating="CustomersGrid_Updating"
  AutoGenerateEditButton="true" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceCustomers">
</asp:GridView>
```

The below code works completely fine for me

```
protected void CustomersGrid_Updating ( Object source, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e )
{

bool cancel = true;
object[] keysNewValues = (object[])Array.CreateInstance(typeof(object), e.NewValues.Count);
e.NewValues.Keys.CopyTo(keysNewValues, 0);

object[] keysOldValues = (object[])Array.CreateInstance(typeof(object), e.OldValues.Count);
e.OldValues.Keys.CopyTo(keysOldValues, 0);

 for (int i=0; i<keysNewValues.Count(); i++)
    {
     if ((e.NewValues[keysNewValues[i]] != null) && (e.OldValues[keysOldValues[i]] != null))
        { 

     if ( !(e.NewValues[keysNewValues[i]].ToString().Equals(e.OldValues[keysOldValues[i]])))
    // set cancel to false since you now have atleast one value which is changed
                        cancel = false;
        }
if ((e.NewValues[keysNewValues[i]] != null) && (e.OldValues[keysOldValues[i]] == null))
            {
                cancel = false;
            }
if ((e.NewValues[keysNewValues[i]] == null) && (e.OldValues[keysOldValues[i]] != null))
            {
                cancel = false;
            }
     }


     if (cancel)
      e.Cancel = true;

    }
```

**Make sure, if a Newvalue is set `null`, then the Column allows null for the same else it will throw an exception . Although it will then needs to  be handeled by using Try & Catch block.**
In case if any value is null ( OLD & NEW values), its coming as `null` since the `e.NewValues` collection is of type : `system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary`. also checked from debugging seen below:

[image]

Comment: Doesn't like keysNewValues.Count(). There's a red underline under "Count". I'm guessing I'm missing a reference? Mine are: using System; using System.IO; using System.Web.UI; using System.Web.UI.WebControls; using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls; using System.Data.SqlClient; using System.Data; using Infragistics.Web.UI.GridControls;

Comment: try : using System.Linq;

Comment: This looks like it might be a winner, but it seems to not like the fact that sometimes e.Values[keysNewValues[i]].ToString() is NULL and e.OldValues[keysOldValues[i]] is EMPTY (i.e. ""). I'm getting an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error. It won't let me use IsNullOrEmpty on it, do you have any other suggestions?  BTW, I tested it with records or portions of records where both variables have values and it works with those pieces, so it looks like the NULL is throwing it off.

Comment: Yes, Correct!!!. You need to add null check. edited my answer and also cross verified using debugging. see the image.

Comment: A new issue arises; The 2 arrays (keysNewValues and keysOldValues) do not line up.  That is, if I append the values to a string and then look at the strings when it's finished with its loop, Value 12 in the New array corresponds to Value 14 in the Old array.  Therefore, it's always going to think at least one of the values has changed.  Is there any way to ensure the arrays are ordered identically?

Comment: I don't see the 2 arrays not aligned identically. You can use 'Count' on both arrays and see if they are having same number of items. Next thing, when appending values to a string, then definitely, null values will be skipped , i.e. means each null item will result in one item less. However, the point to understand is that both arrays will have equal number of items. that is: say item 2 can be null in newValue and not null in old values. This is why comparison is done key be key using index of items.

Comment: I updated the code slightly so that NULL values are converted to "", so they can be properly compared.  Here's my arrays: NEW: ", , , , , , , , , , , , ABBOTT,DESHELL, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , 8/14/2013 9:54:12 AM, , , , , , , , BALDWIN,DEVAN, , , , 306882, , , , , , , , , , 4875, , , , , "  OLD: ", , , , , , , , , , , , , , ABBOTT,DESHELL, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , 8/14/2013 9:54:12 AM, , , , , , , , BALDWIN,DEVAN, , , , , , , , , , 306882, , , 4875, , , , , "  Put them in a text editor, they don't line up.

Comment: did you verified the count values for both arrays, also please once check items at  index: 12 in keyNewValues & 14 in keyOldvalues.

Comment: This might be native to the WebDataGrid control, but there is no "NewValues" object.  Instead, it's just "Values".  When I hover over e.Values.Count, it shows 73.  When I hover over e.OldValues.Count, it shows 73.  When I expand both (you know, it comes up with a box and a plus sign inside it), the lists of values are in a different order.  I checked this with test data.  As odd as it sounds, the array of Values is in a different order than the array of OldValues.

Comment: Please see my images I added to my original post.  For some reason, when I did the print screen the list of values became really faint, but if you look you can see they're not in the same order.

Comment: Ok. So figured out why this is happening. i.e. why there is NO one 2 one corespondence between keys. This is happening because I see some new columns added when trying to update. For example, in the images provided by you, I see there are 2 columns: CBH_Proclaim & MediCare_Hospital  present in old values but NOT in new values. Also, in newvalues: Medicom column has been added, which is originally absent in oldvalues. There is something interesting happening in your Updating method. Pleae check from where columns are getting added or removed. Please show me your updating method.

Comment: Also make sure you are not hiding or displaying columns dynamically.

Comment: There are 73 columns, so I could only display the first 14 or so.  If you scroll down the list, all the columns are in both arrays, just in a different order.  This control is a 3rd party from a company called Infragistics.  I'm going to post on their MB and see if they have any answers, but if you think of anything else please let me know.

Comment: ok. Its finally we got the reason . Somehow because the Order of Columns changes and that's why the two arrays are having different order of  corresponding keys & hence the Values. Definitely the code shown by me will work only if order of columns doesn't changes. Please let me know what the Party Infragistics  has to say.

Answer (score 0):

Only way I can think of is to actually compare every field in the `WHERE` part, except for the time stamp field

example code:

```
UPDATE [tblclaimRoster] 
SET [EE Name] = @EE_Name,
    [EEID] = @EEID,
    [Mgr Name] = @Mgr_Name,
    ...
WHERE
    [RosterID] = @RosterID AND
    ([EE Name] <> @EE_Name OR [Mgr Name] <> @Mgr_Name OR ...)
```